# set a class property as a float or decimal value when being echo'd

Tags: php

i'm curious how something like this would work

```
class Test
{
    public $price;
}

$obj = new Test();
$obj->price = 4500.00;

echo $obj->price;
```

how can I return that value as `4500.00` and not `4500`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo number_format($obj->price,2);
```

If you don't what the thousands seperator:

```
echo number_format($obj->price,2,'.','');
```

See [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

Comment: i had thought of this, but when I do an echo using that I get Warning: number_format() expects parameter 1 to be double, string

Comment: It means, `$obj->price` is not holding a double or a string. You can cast it as a double: number_format((double)$obj->price,2);`

Comment: I have been trying (float) and all this time I needed it to be (double) oh geez. Thanks

Comment: @Eli: No problem. Glad to help. Feel free to accept the answer if it answered your question.